# How to set seconds to 00 in timestamp?

Tags: php

I need to get timestamp with seconds set to 00. I do this like this:

```
$time = time();
$time = substr($time, 0, strlen($time) - 2) . '00';
```

But the result is still with seconds, for example:

- 1384512500 2013-11-15 12:48:20
- 1384512400 2013-11-15 12:46:40

How to remove seconds or set it to 00 ?

Comment: I tested your code on my computer, it's showing 00 at the end.
echo $time = time();echo " ";
echo $time = substr($time, 0, strlen($time) - 2) . '00';

Comment: @web2students.com is it showing a unix timestamp with 00 at the end, or is it showing a formatted date with 00 at the end? If your unix timestamp mod 60 = 0 then you are lucky and unix timestamp + formatted date end with 00 seconds. Update: according to the code in your comment, you have a unix timestamp, OP needs a formatted date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$time = time();
$time -= $time % 60;
```

Comment: +1.. my brain did understand your logic at first sight but I would never came to this code without seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

A timestamp represents the number of seconds since 19xx somewhat. Setting the last 2 digits to zero does not build a DateTime with 00 seconds.

```
$time = new DateTime();
echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i'), ':00';
```

This does.